# Open RAW image files in GIMP

Tags: gimp, image-processing

Is there any plugin for GIMP to edit RAW photo files? I tried ufraw which is quite popular, but its GUI sucks to the degree of being unusable.

Moreover, I want to edit my files in GIMP, using GIMP tools that I am used to, not in ufraw-like plugin. Any ideas?

I am not interested in stand-alone applications like Raw Therappe. My goal is to edit RAW files in GIMP the same way as any other image file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install package *gimp-dcraw*. This is simple plugin that uses dcraw to decode RAW files and pass them to GIMP. All editing like colors, tone curves, stamps etc. are done with GIMP built-in editing tools, plugin only asks for optional decoding parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Darktable  can also edit raw images and it has much better color accuracy than GIMP with the *gimp-dcraw* plug-in. Darktable can import a variety of standard, raw and high dynamic range image formats (e.g. JPEG, CR2, NEF, HDR, PFM, RAF … ). I've also tried opening raw images in Krita image editor and the colors in Krita aren't true to the original image either. Darktable beats all the other image editors that I tested for color accuracy hands down.

To install the Darktable in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install darktable
```

[image]
<sup>**Original image**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Colors aren't accurate in GIMP + gimp-dcraw**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Darktable**</sup>

Comment: I personally prefer darktable. It gives two edges to edit your images. It is like Photoshop + Lightroom (actually somewhat better than adobe)

Comment: darktable is available through the apt repo. `sudo apt install darktable`.