# GIMP installed via FlatPak asks me to install DarkTable, but I've already installed it. (not via Flatpak). How can I get GIMP to find it?

Tags: gimp, flatpak, darktable

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 MATE and recently downloaded GIMP 2.10 as a Flatpak. I also have Darktable loaded (not a Flatpak) as I work with RAW format photos. I want to be able to post process RAW images using GIMP as well as Darktable, but when I try to load a RAW image into GIMP I receive a dialogue that asks me to install Darktable. I'm assuming I need to have Darktable in my path, if that is what is needed I just don't know how to do that. Any comments and guidance will be appreciated.

This is my current $PATH:-

```
/home/-/bin:/home/-/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Gimp itself doesn't support the `raw`-format. You can not process `raw`-images with Gimp. https://www.gimp.org/features/

Answer (score 3):

Installing Gimp plug-ins isn't a matter of PATH contents. To add plugins to Gimp you put the executable (a `file-*` in it can load/save files) in specific directories:

- `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/plugins` (for "regular" installs, not flatpak ones)
- the `plugins` directory in your [Gimp user profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/)

The equivalents for flatpak installs would be:

- `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.gimp.GIMP/current/[...]/files/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/`
- `.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins`

But the problem with flatpack-ed Gimp is that it has its own runtime, so using executables not compiled for the flatpak environment isn't guaranteed to run smoothly.

IMHO, flatpak is just a stopgap measure for people stuck on 16.04, since you are on 18.04 you should add the [Gimp PPA](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) to your software sources and do regular installs from that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the original question asked for how to change `PATH` before it was edited. [The questions aren't supposed to be edited in fundamental ways that make correct answers incorrect](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16366/616451).

---

I'm not sure how to fix the problem with GIMP, but modifying the `PATH` for all users is easy enough. You just create a few files in `/etc/profile.d` and restart:

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Check whether Darktable starts when you try running it (it might already be in the `PATH`). If so, stop. If not, continue.
3. Run `sudo nano /etc/profile.d/darktable.sh`
4. Add a line, replacing the path below with the proper path:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/darktable/bin
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save.
6. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the given filename.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano`.
8. Run `sudo nano /etc/profile.d/darktable.csh`
9. Add a line, replacing the path below with the proper path:

   ```
   setenv PATH ${PATH}:/path/to/darktable/bin
   ```
10. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save.
11. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the given filename.
12. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano`.
13. Close the terminal window.
14. Restart your system.

Comment: I have run darktable form a terminal and the following appeared:-

Comment: Not a solution to this problem, which is an issue with the flatpak packaging format.

Comment: @vanadium The original question asked for this solution. It's been edited. [Questions aren't supposed to be edited to invalidate answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16366/616451).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex When I reviewed this answer after it had been flagged I noticed that it was wrong, but skipped the review in order to give you a chance to edit it.

Comment: @karel The answer isn't wrong for the original title question, which was repeated in the body of the original question.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex, I asked the moderators to take a look.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex It's too late to have a look, because the OP isn't asking for an answer anymore. The OP edited the question himself and wrote that he's abandoning the question because he decided to leave things as they are, therefore the question is off topic because it's not reproducible.

Comment: The question was edited by me after @vanadium's original comment in any case - your answer had already been downvoted. And I only changed the title to match the question body and corrected the formatting. If you want to answer the simple question of how to modify PATH, there are innumerable questions you could post an answer to. But I don't think this question is a dupe of any such question, and should have a unique title to reflect what it is actually asking about instead of a generic XY problem title that will confuse visitors

Answer (score -1):

Any supported version of GIMP can open raw images with *gimp-dcraw* from the default Ubuntu repositories. The gimp-dcraw plug-in integrates with GIMP apt packages only, it does not integrate with either GIMP snap packages or GIMP flatpak packages. Therefore if you're a stickler for GIMP version 2.10, you'll have to wait for two weeks until Ubuntu 18.10 which has this version of GIMP in the repos is released.

To install gimp-dcraw open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gimp-dcraw
```

The proof that this plug-in works is shown in this screenshot.

[image]
<sup>**off color raw image in GIMP + gimp-dcraw in Ubuntu 18.04**</sup>

The problem with this method is that the colors of the raw image look off color and not like colors in the original image. The water in the image is supposed to be blue, not off color. You can see the original image at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508071/open-raw-image-files-in-gimp/1082805#1082805). The solution is to **stay with Darktable**. I tried opening raw images in GIMP, Krita, and Darktable and **only Darktable** has an acceptable level of color accuracy for raw images by default.

Comment: In Flatpak or in a standard Gimp install? The flatpak version suffers from integration problems, in the early versions, it had its own `/tmp` so could not exchange files with other apps.